# Ordenar array bidimensional según string

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente arreglo previamente filtrado.

```
let result = [ [ 'MO021',
    'iPhone 7',
    'Silver',
    '32 gb',
    'Listo para Sellar',
    'Usado',
    'MODULO, BATERIA Y BANDEJA SIM',
    'Buenos Aires',
    0.69,
    '',
    '17/5/2021',
    'Consignacion',
    '' ],
  [ 'MR023',
    'iPhone 7',
    'Black',
    '32 gb',
    'Listo para Sellar',
    'Usado',
    'LIMPIAR AURIS-CAMBIO CAMARA TRASERA',
    'Santa Fe',
    0.94,
    '',
    '30/3/2021',
    'Compra Directa',
    '' ],
  [ 'SP010',
    'iPhone 7',
    'Black',
    '32 gb',
    'Listo para Sellar',
    'Usado',
    'modulo orinigal con detalle',
    'Cordoba',
    0.86,
    '',
    '19/9/2020',
    'Consignacion',
    '' ] ];
```

quiero ordenar el array `result` según la ubicación, priorizando una o varias string (que seria la ubicacion requerida), es decir que la ubicación "Santa Fe" este en la posición 0 del array y "Cordoba" a la posición 1 del array, el resto en cualquier posición.
Para un array simple funciona, pero uno bidimensional no.

```
  var makeFnSortArray = ( ...criteria ) => {
    var order = criteria.reduce( ( o, item, i) => {
      o[item] = i+1;
      console.log(o);
      return o;
    }, {})      
    return (a, b) => {
      if ( (order[b] && !order[a]) || order[a] > order[b] ) return 1;
      if ( (order[a] && !order[b]) || (order[a] < order[b]) ) return -1;
      if ( a > b ) return 1;
      if ( a < b ) return -1;
      return 0;
    }
  }

   let fnOrderUbicacion = makeFnSortArray("Santa Fe","Cordoba");
   result =  result.sort(fnOrderUbicacion );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si entendí bien la pregunta, se puede usar `.reduce` para primero dividir lo que se va a ordenar de lo que no se va a ordenar, luego `.sort` para ordenar el array "ordenable", para luego unir ambos arrays:

```js
let result = [
  ['MO021',
    'iPhone 7',
    'Silver',
    '32 gb',
    'Listo para Sellar',
    'Usado',
    'MODULO, BATERIA Y BANDEJA SIM',
    'Buenos Aires',
    0.69,
    '',
    '17/5/2021',
    'Consignacion',
    ''
  ],
  ['MR023',
    'iPhone 7',
    'Black',
    '32 gb',
    'Listo para Sellar',
    'Usado',
    'LIMPIAR AURIS-CAMBIO CAMARA TRASERA',
    'Santa Fe',
    0.94,
    '',
    '30/3/2021',
    'Compra Directa',
    ''
  ],
  ['SP010',
    'iPhone 7',
    'Black',
    '32 gb',
    'Listo para Sellar',
    'Usado',
    'modulo orinigal con detalle',
    'Cordoba',
    0.86,
    '',
    '19/9/2020',
    'Consignacion',
    ''
  ]
];

const orden = ["Santa Fe", "Cordoba"]

const arrAordenar = result.reduce((p, c) => {

    orden.includes(c[7]) ? p[0].push(c) : p[1].push(c);

    return p;
  }

  , [
    [],
    []
  ])

const arrOrdenado = arrAordenar[0].sort((a, b) => orden.indexOf(a) - orden.indexOf(b))

const res = [...arrOrdenado, arrAordenar[1][0]]

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Perfecto me sirvio, solo que el resultado difiere un poco, me devuelve [[[a],[b],[[c]]] es array bidimensional dentro, reemplace la ultima parte por         arrAordenar[1].splice(0, 0, ...arrOrdenado);
console.log(arrAordenar[1]) para que no cree ese nuevo bidimensional.

Comment: si quieres modificarlo para que quede correcto, igual me solucion la pregunta!

Comment: El segundo array tenía una dimensión mas, a eso te refieres? Cambié el resultado por `const res = [...arrOrdenado, arrAordenar[1][0]]`

Comment: claro, a eso me referia